# Displaying flex items in row on larger screens, but stacked vertically on smaller screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I am creating a simple homepage for my client. I am using flex-box to layout the main content on the page. I have 2 `div.container`'s that contain 2 `img`'s each.

In desktop view, I want the 2 `div.container`'s to display inline, but when the website is in mobile view, I want them to display stacked.

I also want the rest of the content to remain stacked no matter what view it is in.

How do i accomplish this?

```js
function setHeight() {
 $('.img-c').css('height', $('.img-c').innerWidth());
}

setInterval(setHeight, 10);
```

```css
:root {
  background: #fff;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  background: #0a0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

li.selected {
  color: orange;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  color: springgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li.selected:hover {
  color: #ff7700;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

main p {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 80%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}

main p:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

main hr {
  width: 100%;
  background: #0a0;
  height: 1px;
}

.img-c {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #000;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 416px) {
  #bottom {
    display: block;
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .img-c {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 358px) {
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  nav ul li:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #0c0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/CompImmer_logo_final_web4.png" id="logo" alt="logo"/>
  <nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="selected">Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Classes</li>
    <li>Jobs</li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c"/>
    <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/5.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c" style="background: magenta"/>
      </div>
       <div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/1.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c"/>
    <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/4.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c" style="background: magenta"/>
    </div>
  <p>Are you looking for computer classes that go beyond the typical summer camp or one-day experience?</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>Does your child have an interest in coding or computer hardware and want to learn what to do next?</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>Computer Immersion has the answer!</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>We teach computer science and tech culture to children who are 12-18 years old. Our classes immerse students in a wide range of hardware and software related topics such as scripting, coding, “tech speak”, networking, and hardware.</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>Our classes are taught by instructors with real world industry experience and meet for 9-week sessions at locations convenient for you.</p>
  <hr/>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

STEP 1:

- Wrap all four images in one flex container.

  ```
  <div id="container">
      <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c"/>
      <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/5.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c" style="background: magenta"/>
      <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/1.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c"/>
      <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/4.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c" style="background: magenta"/>
  </div>
  ```

---

STEP 2:

- Style the flex items for larger screens.

  ```
  .container {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: space-around;
  }
  ```

---

STEP 3

- Style the flex items for smaller screens.

  ```
  @media screen and (max-width: 416px) {
     .container {
          flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
     .img-c {
          width: 50%;
          border: 2px solid white;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
  }
  ```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/kg45cu3z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

- wrap your image `.container` divs with another div.
  e.x.: `<div class="gallery">`
- add the flex property only to the wrapper div:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

view code snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/3uavncu2/1/

**bonus**, try these Flexbox tutorials:
http://flexboxin5.com/
http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 0):

you could use a single `.container` and turn it into an inline-flex box.

Your min-width set on img can  be the X values of your breaking points for this container, else sort this within the mediaqueries you already have set.

```js
function setHeight() {
  $('.img-c').css('height', $('.img-c').innerWidth());
}

setInterval(setHeight, 10);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  /* seems redundant but necessary, not inherited from parent flexbox */
}
:root {
  background: #fff;
}
#logo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  background: #0a0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
li.selected {
  color: orange;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  color: springgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul li.selected:hover {
  color: #ff7700;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
main p {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 80%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}
main p:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
main hr {
  width: 100%;
  background: #0a0;
  height: 1px;
}
.img-c {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #000;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 416px) {
  #bottom {
    display: block;
    order: 1;
  }
  .img-c {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 358px) {
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav ul li:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #0c0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/CompImmer_logo_final_web4.png" id="logo" alt="logo" />
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="selected">Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Classes</li>
      <li>Jobs</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c" />
    <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/5.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c" style="background: magenta" />
    <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/1.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c" />
    <img src="http://www.computerimmersion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/4.jpg" alt="img" class="img-c" style="background: magenta" />
  </div>
  <p>Are you looking for computer classes that go beyond the typical summer camp or one-day experience?</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>Does your child have an interest in coding or computer hardware and want to learn what to do next?</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>Computer Immersion has the answer!</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>We teach computer science and tech culture to children who are 12-18 years old. Our classes immerse students in a wide range of hardware and software related topics such as scripting, coding, “tech speak”, networking, and hardware.</p>
  <hr/>
  <p>Our classes are taught by instructors with real world industry experience and meet for 9-week sessions at locations convenient for you.</p>
  <hr/>
</main>
```